# Updating the Mage registry

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, registry

I was just wondering if it was possible to update the value of a key in the `Mage::registry` without unsetting and resetting the item in the registry.

e.g.

```
$ids = array('1', '2', '3');
Mage::register('testing-key', $ids);

$re_ids = Mage::registry('testing-key');
$re_ids[] = '4';

Mage::registry('testing-key') = $re_ids;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, the `Mage` class only provides three different methods to deal with the registry:

- `register`
- `unregister`
- `registry`

Thus, you will have to call `unregister` then `register` again if you want to update an entry in the registry.

Comment: Is there a way to lock a registry item? What I mean is that say there's a process that multiple users can go through at the same time, but it uses the same registry item. I want only 1 users to be able to read, unregister and re-register an item at a time. Sorry if these questions seem dumb, I'm trying to find the best solution to a problem, and trying as many different solutions as I can to find the best one :)

Comment: @Skytiger well that's an entire different question. I suggest you mark this one as answered and open a new question with the comment you just made.

Comment: Thanks, I'll create a new question for it. Was just waiting for the timer to run out so that I could mark this as answered :)